# MySQL query is not working when I use single apostrophe symbol ( ' ) in query

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating simple form using PHP and MySQl. But When I enter the apostrophe symbol (') as input in one of the textbox in the form, the query is not working. It does not insert any record to the database due to apostrophe symbol.

Following is the simple example of MySQL query using PHP.

```
mysql_query("insert into users (username,passwd,name,mobile) values ('$username','$passwd','$name','$mobile')")
```

Comment: Use Prepare statement and stop using deprecated `mysql_query`

Comment: Read something about escaping entry data.

Comment: And whats the error that you were getting

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions anymore because they're deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead. See the PHP doc for more information about prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape input data, when you're using mysql, you need `mysql_real_escape_string` function.

```
mysql_query("insert into users (username,passwd,name,mobile) values (
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($username) . "', 
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($passwd) . "',
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($name) . "',
    '" . mysql_real_escape_string($mobile) . "')"
);
```

As a bonus you get protection against SQL injection.

Comment: Don't use mysql_* functions anymore because they're deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli instead. See the PHP doc for more information about prepared statements.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER: you comment is off topic. If OP uses mysql, the correct answer is to use mysql functions. Put your comment under question, not under all answers. Thanks. (PS. you're right, but you have to see a context too).

Comment: But you could still mention the deprecation of mysql_* in your answer and show proper alternatives like PDO with prepared statements.

Comment: Panther - your answer is off topic. As long as the OP continues to use the deprecated API (and so forgoing prepared statements), they remain vulnerable to injection

Answer (score 0):

Because there are a lot of outdated answers I will give you a clean(er) solution by using PDO. You should switch immideatly to PDO or mysql**i** because your code will most likely crash in a few months/in less than a year (as soon as PHP7 is out):

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:...');

$stmnt = $pdo->prepare("insert into users (username,passwd,name,mobile) values (?, ?, ?, ?)");

$stmnt->execute(array($username, $passwd, $name, $mobile));
```

Answer (score 0):

As fields username, password, phone does not contain single quotes, you need not to use any function to remove quotes from form data, you can simply use query like :

```
mysql_query("insert into users (username,passwd,name,mobile) values ('".$username."','".$passwd."','".$name."','".$mobile."')")
```

or you can remove quotes from form data if required.

Answer (score -2):

Use htmlspecialchars() function to encode single quotes and insert into Database and while fetching that data use htmlspecialchars_decode() function which decodes back to single quotes.

Comment: bad practise. instead, use prepared statements or proper quoting.